# Python: replacing an element in an array without changing array shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to replace some of the letters in the array below with the letter 'K'. But every time I use `numpy.replace` and then `numpy.delete` it changes the shape of my array. Is there a way I  can change a selected letter in the array without changing the array shape?

```
AA = [['A', 'B', 'C']]
AA = np.array(AA)
AA = np.repeat(AA, 5, axis=0)


AA = np.delete(AA, (1))
AA = np.insert(AA, (1), 'K')
```

I want to be able to replace any of the letters in the let array with a 'K'.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You initially define AA as a List with one element, the nested List ['A', 'B', 'C']. I imagine that's where you're hitting the difficulty.

Comment: What do you mean by "replace any of the letters in the let array with a `'K'`?  Do you want to replace them by position?  By value?  Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on what you are trying to accomplish and how you imagine things will turn out.

you start out with a 5 X 3 array , 
then you delete one element 
now you have 14 elements. what shape did you imagine it would be in?

maybe you want direct assignment

```
AA[1,2]='K'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace every instance of one letter with another, try something like

```
A = np.array(list('ABC'))
A = np.repeat(A, 5, axis=0)
A[np.where(A == 'A')] = 'K'
```

The numpy function `numpy.where(A == 'A')` returns a set of indices indicating where in `A` there is the letter `"A"`.  We then use those indices to slice the `A` array and do a reassignment.  More explicitly,

```
inds = np.where(A == 'A')
A[inds] = 'K'
```

Additionally, if you want to choose an index (say position 1 in the array), and replace that letter and all similar letters with 'K', you could do something like

```
A = np.array(list('ABC'))
A = np.repeat(A, 5, axis=0)
A[np.where(A == A[1])] = 'K'
```